# VS Code: Compiled with 5 warnings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, webpack, create-react-app

Проект был создан с помощью create-react-app.

VS Code на каком то этапе начал запускать проект с 5 ошибками. В чем может быть проблема? Пробовал обновлять зависимости и заново качать node_modules - не помогло...

```
Compiled with warnings.

Failed to parse source map from '/Users/igormokhov/webDev/Projects/React/my-books/node_modules/html-dom-parser/src/client/constants.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/igormokhov/webDev/Projects/React/my-books/node_modules/html-dom-parser/src/client/constants.ts'

Failed to parse source map from '/Users/igormokhov/webDev/Projects/React/my-books/node_modules/html-dom-parser/src/client/domparser.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/igormokhov/webDev/Projects/React/my-books/node_modules/html-dom-parser/src/client/domparser.ts'

Failed to parse source map from '/Users/igormokhov/webDev/Projects/React/my-books/node_modules/html-dom-parser/src/client/html-to-dom.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/igormokhov/webDev/Projects/React/my-books/node_modules/html-dom-parser/src/client/html-to-dom.ts'

Failed to parse source map from '/Users/igormokhov/webDev/Projects/React/my-books/node_modules/html-dom-parser/src/client/utilities.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/igormokhov/webDev/Projects/React/my-books/node_modules/html-dom-parser/src/client/utilities.ts'

Failed to parse source map from '/Users/igormokhov/webDev/Projects/React/my-books/node_modules/style-to-object/src/index.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/igormokhov/webDev/Projects/React/my-books/node_modules/style-to-object/src/index.ts'

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

WARNING in ./node_modules/html-dom-parser/lib/client/constants.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/Users/igormokhov/webDev/Projects/React/my-books/node_modules/html-dom-parser/src/client/constants.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/igormokhov/webDev/Projects/React/my-books/node_modules/html-dom-parser/src/client/constants.ts'

WARNING in ./node_modules/html-dom-parser/lib/client/domparser.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/Users/igormokhov/webDev/Projects/React/my-books/node_modules/html-dom-parser/src/client/domparser.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/igormokhov/webDev/Projects/React/my-books/node_modules/html-dom-parser/src/client/domparser.ts'

WARNING in ./node_modules/html-dom-parser/lib/client/html-to-dom.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/Users/igormokhov/webDev/Projects/React/my-books/node_modules/html-dom-parser/src/client/html-to-dom.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/igormokhov/webDev/Projects/React/my-books/node_modules/html-dom-parser/src/client/html-to-dom.ts'

WARNING in ./node_modules/html-dom-parser/lib/client/utilities.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/Users/igormokhov/webDev/Projects/React/my-books/node_modules/html-dom-parser/src/client/utilities.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/igormokhov/webDev/Projects/React/my-books/node_modules/html-dom-parser/src/client/utilities.ts'

WARNING in ./node_modules/style-to-object/cjs/index.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/Users/igormokhov/webDev/Projects/React/my-books/node_modules/style-to-object/src/index.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/igormokhov/webDev/Projects/React/my-books/node_modules/style-to-object/src/index.ts'

webpack compiled with 5 warnings
```